# how to remove index.php in url htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

how to remove index.php in my url

my htaccess is

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

i visit my site as `http://domain.com/index.php` it redirects to `http://domain.com` How could I solve this problem?

Comment: But going back to `http://domain.com` is what you want right (after removing index.php)?

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```